# What does IllegalStateException: database not open mean?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm running the delete method in SQLiteDatabase in my code and it says:

> IllegalStateException : database not open in the log.

Here's the code snippet:

```
String whereClause = getWhereClause(compareColumn, compareValue);

db.delete(tableName, whereClause, null);
```

Here's the logcat being generated.

```
04-03 16:32:09.514: E/DB DELETE ERROR(310): java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open
04-03 16:32:09.514: W/System.err(310): java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open
04-03 16:32:09.523: W/System.err(310):  at    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.delete(SQLiteDatabase.java:1585)
04-03 16:32:09.523: W/System.err(310):  at mylibs.testshop.deleteRow(testshop.java:78)
04-03 16:32:09.523: W/System.err(310):  at com.example.testapp.shopping_list$1.onClick(shopping_list.java:98)
04-03 16:32:09.523: W/System.err(310):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-03 16:32:09.523: W/System.err(310):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
04-03 16:32:09.523: W/System.err(310):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-03 16:32:09.533: W/System.err(310):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-03 16:32:09.533: W/System.err(310):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-03 16:32:09.533: W/System.err(310):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-03 16:32:09.533: W/System.err(310):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 16:32:09.533: W/System.err(310):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-03 16:32:09.533: W/System.err(310):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)  
04-03 16:32:09.533: W/System.err(310):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)  
04-03 16:32:09.533: W/System.err(310):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I created a constructor at the top of my database class. Helper is an instance of SQLiteOpenHelper,the code :

```
 public testshop(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
 // create or open the database
    helper = new CustomSQLiteOpenHelper(context);
    this.db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

}
```

So should I use `getWriteableDatabase()` every time I want to query the database or is it once?

Comment: It means you have to create a connection to the database before executing queries. :)

Comment: open your db, then you can use it.

Comment: How can I do that coz I can run other queries like insert in the same class. Only delete gives an error. @kocko

Comment: How do i do that? @Vyger

Comment: I need to see how you set up your db - if you are using the dbHelper or not.

Comment: Have you already closed your database before delete()?

Comment: Nope, I haven't closed my database. @laalto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get access to database first. Usually, when You used SQLiteOpenHelper, before delete You should do:

```
db = this.getWriteableDatabase() // "this" is a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper
```

Comment: I created a constructor at the top of my database class. Helper is an instance of SQLiteOpenHelper,the code :   `public testshop(Context context) {
  this.context = context;

  // create or open the database
  helper = new CustomSQLiteOpenHelper(context);
  this.db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
  
 }`              So should I use getWriteableDatabase() everytime I want to query the database or is it once?

Comment: No, opening database once should be enough. Try to create new instance of Your class before deleting. There may be actually a problem with context of application. Also check, if whereClause is proper.

Answer (score 0):

like both comments (so far) have said, you need to open the database for writing. Take a look at the docs (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html). The SQliteOpenHelper is pretty easy to use and does a lot of this stuff for you.

There is a lot of help out there for this type of thing, but writing and reading to the database directly is not a recipe for success IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

may be you should this:

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = mContext.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

before the

```
db = this.getWriteableDatabase()
```